# Uncaught ReferenceError: SwaggerUIBundle is not defined nodejs netlify

Tags: javascript, node.js, swagger, netlify

I am trying to setup my netlify code integrated with nodejs. Without netlify my swagger was working fine but after the netlify integrations My swagger page is not loading and throwing this error.

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at swagger-ui-bundle.js:3:1)
swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js:3 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js:3:1)
swagger-ui-init.js:200 Uncaught ReferenceError: SwaggerUIBundle is not defined
at window.onload (swagger-ui-init.js:200:7)

My netlify.toml is

```
[functions]
  external_node_modules = ["express"]
  node_bundler = "esbuild"
[[redirects]]
  force = true
  from = "/api/*"
  status = 200
  to = "/.netlify/functions/api/:splat"
```

and my api.ts is

// YOUR_BASE_DIRECTORY/netlify/functions/api.ts

```
import express, { Router } from "express";
import serverless from "serverless-http";
import uploadRoutes from '../../routes/uploadRoutes'
import fileRoutes from '../../routes/fileRoutes'
import userRoutes from '../../routes/userRoutes'
import authRoutes from '../../routes/auth'
import config from '../../config/config'
import swaggerUi from 'swagger-ui-express'
import swaggerJSDoc from 'swagger-jsdoc'
import upload from '../../multerConfig'
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'
import connectToDatabase from '../../config/db'
import cors from 'cors'
import SwaggerUIBundle from 'swagger-ui-dist/swagger-ui-bundle';
import SwaggerUIStandalonePreset from 'swagger-ui-dist/swagger-ui-standalone-preset';



const swaggerSpec = swaggerJSDoc({
    encoding: 'utf8',
    failOnErrors: false,
    verbose: false,
    format: 'yaml', // or 'json', depending on your preference
    swaggerDefinition: config.swaggerDefinition,
    definition: {}, // or provide your Swagger definition here if needed
    apis: config.apiPaths,
});

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
// Handle preflight requests for all routes
app.options('*', cors()); 
// Serve Swagger UI
app.use('/api/api-docs', swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerSpec));
const router = Router();

// Enable CORS


router.get('/hello', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World test v1!'));

app.use("/api", router);





// Middleware to set Access-Control-Allow-Origin header for all routes
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    next();
  });
app.use(express.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ limit: '50mb' }));


// Parse JSON bodies
app.use(bodyParser.json());
// Parse URL-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
// Use the upload routes
app.use(uploadRoutes);

// Use the file routes
app.use('/api', fileRoutes);
app.use(upload.single('file'));
app.use('/api', userRoutes);
app.use('/api/auth', authRoutes); // Fixed missing '/' at the beginning

// MongoDB URI
const mongoURI = config.mongoURI;

// Call the function to establish MongoDB connection
connectToDatabase(mongoURI);

export const handler = serverless(app);
```

Can anyone please guide me what I am doing wrong , I tried one solution of changing the order of swagger before route but there is no luck on that.